# Heroku PHP and Node.js in the same app

Tags: php, node.js, heroku

I'm using a Node package called [exec-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-php) to execute PHP functions within Node.js app.

I would like to push that app to **Heroku**, but I'm wondering how to make that, and how that would be in the PHP bin locally.

I'm using `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php`. What would be the path to **PHP bin** in **Heroku**?

I tested **vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2** but it doesn't work, so what would be the **path to PHP binary** in Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bin directory in heroku is : .heroku/php/bin/php

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to inform the build API that you'd like to use multiple buildpacks. Try:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/php
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

Then you can inspect the compiled slug via `heroku run bash` to verify that the bins are where you expect them to be.

Comment: I get this error when trying to  `git push heroku master` : `Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/php` `

Comment: That sounds like you've got the buildpacks out of order. Did you run those commands in the order above? What's the output from running `heroku buildpacks -a <app name>`?

Comment: this the output === dfc-insta-back Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/php
2. heroku/nodejs

Comment: Do you have a `composer.json` file in the root on your project? You may need to run `composer update` and check everything into git before pushing as well.